# What's the syntax for identifying repository URLs by position in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I'm looking at the following [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-variables-289277087.html#Bamboovariables-Build-specificvariables) for `Bamboo variables/Build-specific variables` and there's the caveat about the position notation...

> In the variable names from the table, `<position>` is an optional
>   parameter that specifies the position of the repository in the plan's
>   repository list. If omitted, the first repository in the list is used.

I'm guessing it's referring to an integer literal to essentially index into your list of Repositories used for the build plan. What exactly would the syntax be for using this in an environment variable export field like in an MSBuild task?

Say I have two repositories

```
Sources
Scripts
```

[image: Source Repositories Plan Configuration]
What's the means of referring to these via the environment variable syntax

```
bamboo.planRepository.<position>.repositoryUrl
```

Could be one of these combinations depending on if its 0 or 1 based indexing, and assuming the index literal is meant to be substituted  for `<position>`

```
Sources    bamboo.planRepository.0.repositoryUrl
Scripts    bamboo.planRepository.1.repositoryUrl

Sources    bamboo.planRepository.1.repositoryUrl
Scripts    bamboo.planRepository.0.repositoryUrl

Sources    bamboo.planRepository.1.repositoryUrl
Scripts    bamboo.planRepository.2.repositoryUrl

Sources    bamboo.planRepository.2.repositoryUrl
Scripts    bamboo.planRepository.1.repositoryUrl
```

I've been experimenting with my SCM team on a 4.0.1 release of Bamboo and we haven't seemed to nail it so far, but haven't exhaustively tried all the combinations yet.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using it is correct. The indexing starts from 1. I just tried, works fine for Bamboo version 6.10.